# Static variable is sometimes not storing correctly

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to generate a nonce (unique key) for the Content Security Policy on a site. The idea is that the nonce is generated the first time that it is requested, then that nonce is returned each time after that (within the single HTTP request). This is the code that I'm using

```
class Csp {
  private static $nonce = NULL;

  public static function nonce () {
    if (!isset(self::$nonce)) {
      self::$nonce = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(15));
    }
    return self::$nonce;
  }
}
```

It's being called by

```
\namespace\Csp::nonce();
```

The function is called several times on each request, and sometimes it returns different values. For example, the function is called both while sending the HTTP headers and while generating the page body content, and sometimes (probably more often than 1 in 20 times), a different value is being sent in the HTTP header and in the body of the response, which is triggering the Content Security Policy (so bad things are happening).

Also, probably unrelated, when I tried to use `static::` rather than `self::`, I was unable to set the variable. I can't find documentation on this, so I'm not sure whether it's a feature or not.

I'm using PHP 5.6.9 on Apache 2.4.10, running on Debian.

Comment: Maybe for some reasons apache decides to create a new instance of php which cause your static variable to be re-initialised.

Comment: @litelite surely that wouldn't happen within the execution of a program, or anywhere near that often, and it wouldn't change variables... right?

Comment: how can you be sure that it is the same instance? Apache probably shutdown your instance of php which means it started back from scratch. You should probably find a better way to store your nonce. Instead of relying on assumption that your program will never be shutdown. The code of your website isn't a standalone program. the server can and will do whatever it want with it.

Comment: @litelite the idea is that a new one is generated every time the page loads, but sometimes that is changing, *in the middle of the script execution*. I call the function multiple times in one page load, and sometimes a different value is being returned for each. I know it doesn't persist across requests, but it's not persisting *within* a request.

Comment: I have updated the question to hopefully remove any ambiguity.